# Enable CORS, WEBAPP,

Tags: javascript, cors

i am struggling with the following problem. I created a simple webapp that sends via JavaScript „GET“ Operations to a other server.
So the problem is my app is hosted lets say on www.webapp.com/WebContent and the webapp itselfes consumes Data services. This OData Services are hosted on another system www.sap.universityber.com/opu/… so when I want to run the app locally with the reverse proxy (apache) and disable the security settings in chrome everything works fine. But when I want to run it from a normal browser without reverse proxy and the chrome settings it says „NO DATA“, Reason -> CORS.

1. Can somebody in this forum tell me how such a CORS- Enablement work maybe with an example code?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enabling CORS would need to be done by `www.sap.universityber.com/opu/`, not in your web app. If it's an open API, they may offer a JSONP alternative (JSONP isn't subject to the Same Origin Policy, it does an end-run around it, but it *also* needs the cooperation of the server providing the content).

Answer (score 0):

In short, you have to specify in your header  that you accept requests from other domains. An in-depth read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

A brief example:

```
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mozilla.com
```

Do note that this has some implications for your security.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the another system (www.sap.universityber.com/opu/), then you need to set the following response headers in the response from this system for every request:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "www.webapp.com/WebContent",
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
```